# How do I define a XSD like "simple type" in Swagger?

Tags: swagger

I've got a type that is just a string in my yml definition:

```
PlayMode:
  type: string
```

I'd like to use in my generated code, but I get a concrete class. I'm assuming I've not set-up the yml correctly.

In an XSD, this would be a "simpleType".

Comment: How are you referring to this `PlayMode` type?  as an input, output, or property in a model?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, but looks like it has just been fixed by the swagger team: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/243